# How do i get rid of the margins ghostscripts adds?

Tags: pdf, image-processing, png, ghostscript

I want to extract the first page of a PDF as PNG to do some image processing on it with this command:

```
$ gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile='test.png' 'test2.pdf'
```

It works well for most PDFs but it adds a transparent margin on this one: http://ubuntuone.com/23676W4TJPyX6W2pkp5guG

`Gimp` does it as expected (no margin), `convert` has the same issue, `-sDEVICE=jpeg` also.

Is there any way to avoid it ?

Answer (score 5):

Ghostscript doesn't add margins, and it certainly doesn't add transparent ones. THe problem is not with Ghostscript, its with your PDF file. You file contains:

/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
/CropBox [27.5 61.0 567.5 781.0]

Ghostscript uses the MediaBox, other viewers may or may not use the CropBox. If you read the GS documentation you will find the -dUseCropBox switch which directs GS to use the CropBox of a PDF file instead of the MediaBox when setting the media size.

-dEPSCrop isn't going to do anything at all with a PDF file.

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed explanations. Sadly, I could not find anything on this in the man :(

Comment: You mean Unix man pages ? We don't write those, the Ghostscript documentation is in HTML files in gs/doc. See Use.htm, Section 5 Using Ghostscript with PDF files.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, If anyone runs into the same issue, I just found the proper switch: `-dUseCropBox`. The final command is now:

```
$ gs -q  -dUseCropBox -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile='test.png' 'test2.pdf'
```

Comment: Another helpful switch is `-dPDFFitPage`, which can help when the PDF is slightly over-sized.  This may exhibit similar symptoms to margin problems.